# Getting leading digits of a string using Google Guava

Tags: java, guava

Basically, I have some strings like

```
5 - Avenue Rd
9 - Bellamy
21 - Brimley
191 - Highway 27 Rocket
```

And so on. I'm looking for a way using Google `Guava` to return the beginning digits. From what I've researched:

- `CharMatcher.DIGIT.retainFrom` is nice but I want it to stop at the first non-digit character.
- `CharMatcher.DIGIT.trimLeadingFrom` is pretty much what I want, except that it returns the other part of the string where I want a string of digits instead.

Any ideas?

EDIT: added another example.

Expected output for the four examples above:

```
5
9
21
191
```

Comment: Can you give the expected output too. Thx,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite equivalent, but

```
CharMatcher.DIGIT.negate().trimTrailingFrom(string);
```

Or -- a bit more involved, but this will work with intermediate digits --

```
string.substring(0, CharMatcher.DIGIT.negate().indexIn(string));
```

Or, with regexes, albeit with all the overhead that implies --

```
string.replaceAll("^(\\d+).*$", "$1")
```

Comment: I'd say it's pretty much exactly equivalent `:)`

Comment: @MattBall: Nope.  If you input "15 x 22 y", you'll get "15 x 22", not "15".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added a new example which also needs to work with the solution

Comment: The first answer won't work with that input, but the other two will.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just `split()` the string on the "-" sign and then `trim()` and parse...

```
String test ="5 - Avenue Rd";
String[] out = test.split("-");
System.out.println(out[0].trim());
```

We don't need a framework to do that.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using the framework heavily. I know there's a regex solution, but I was curious about an efficient Guava solution

Comment: As i don't know Guava, can't help you there... but mine does solve all your requirements.